# How does factanal() function in R calculate correlations between factors?

Tags: r, analysis

When using the factanal() function from the stats package in R using the promax rotation, you are given factor correlations.

```
tmp = cbind(rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5))
print(factanal(tmp, 3, rotation="promax"))
```

However, I can not seem to find how these correlations are calculated (no help in the R documentation). I also fail to recreate them myself using cor() on the factor scores.

I'm guessing it may be a polychoric correlation, but I can't be certain.

Comment: Welcome to SO Taylor! Does it really give *give factor correlations*? The `correlation` matrix in the output seems to be the `cor(x)` (where x here is the data you used.)

Comment: Thanks Suren, I usually just rely on other people to ask questions, but haven't found an answer for this one! And yes, I am sure it gives factor correlations, which is explicitly stated in the output when printed:

Comment: I see now. It does print the factor correlations. I tried to create the using `cor(output$scores)`, they weren't quite the same.

Comment: And now we have reached the same impasse

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: The problem here: when you have code that doesnt do what you expect it to do, you should disclose example code. Asking us for links to some documetation, library, ... is off topic btw.

Comment: I have now disclosed example code as suggested.

Comment: This would be maybe much better off on stats.stackexchange.com. Take a look [at this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121271/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-r-factanal-output), for example.

Comment: Thanks @Roman, I have posted the question on stats.stackexchange.com too, but am yet to find an answer (the question you linked doesn't use promax and so doesn't produce/address the inter-correlations between factors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its calculated using the following code which can be found here https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/factanal.R:

`tmat <- solve(tmp$rotmat)
 R <- tmat %*% t(tmat)`